# division algorithm provided in Sanjoy Dasgupta

Tags: algorithm, division

I am reading division algorithm in book Algorithms by Sanjoy Dasgupta. Here division algorithm is mentioned as below.

```
function divide(x,y) 
Input: Two n-bit integers x and y, where y ≥ 1 
Output: The quotient and remainder of x divided by y
if x = 0: return (q,r) = (0,0)
(q,r) = divide(x/2,y)
q = 2·q, r = 2·r
if x is odd: r = r + 1 
if r ≥ y: r = r−y, q = q + 1
return (q,r)
```

My questions on above algorithm are

1. How do we write recurrent formulation in simple terms for above algorithm which is missing from book and I am not able to write one.
2. Why are we performing r = r + 1 if x is odd?
3. Why are dong q = 2.q and r = 2.r?

Thanks

Comment: Multiplying by two to compensate for the previous divide by two.

Comment: `How [to] write recurrent formulation` the procedure presented looks recursive to me - can you elaborate what you are getting at with `recurrent`? `Why are dong q = 2.q and r = 2.r` (*are we doing*?) as in What is the purpose of `q = 2·q, r = 2·r`?

Comment: [Sanjoy Dasgupta; Christos Papadimitriou; Umesh Vazirani: *Algorithms*](https://www.mheducation.com/highered/product/algorithms-dasgupta-papadimitriou/M0073523402.html)